# Find edges of intervals in dataframe column and use them for geom_rect xmin-xmax in ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, intervals

I have a data frame consituted by two columns

```
positionx <- c(1:10)
pvalue <- c(0.1, 0.04, 0.03, 0.02, 0.001, 0.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.001, 0.002)
df <- data.frame(cbind(positionx, pvalue))
df
positionx pvalue
1          1  0.100
2          2  0.040
3          3  0.030
4          4  0.020
5          5  0.001
6          6  0.200
7          7  0.500
8          8  0.600
9          9  0.001
10        10  0.002
```

I would like to find in which intervals of values of positionx my pvalue is below a certain treshold, let's say 0.05.
Using 'which' I can find the index of the rows and I could go back to the vlaues of positionx.

```
which(df[,2]<0.05)
[1]  2  3  4  5  9 10
```

Howeverm what I would like are **the edges of the intervals**, with that I mean a result like: 2-5, 9-10

I also tried to use the findInterval function as below

```
int <- c(-10, 0.05, 10)
separation <- findInterval(pvalue,int)
separation
[1] 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 1

df_sep <- data.frame(cbind(df, separation))
df_sep

   positionx pvalue separation
1          1  0.100          2
2          2  0.040          1
3          3  0.030          1
4          4  0.020          1
5          5  0.001          1
6          6  0.200          2
7          7  0.500          2
8          8  0.600          2
9          9  0.001          1
10        10  0.002          1
```

However I am stuck again with a column of numbers, while I want the edges of the intervals that contain 1 in the separation column.
Is there a way to do that?

This is semplified example, in reality I have many plots and for each plot one data frame of this type (just much longer and with pvalues not as easy to judge at a glance).
The reason why I think I need the information of the edges of my intervals, is that I would like to colour the background of my ggplot according to the pvalue. I know I can use geom_rect for it, but I think I need the edges of the intervals in order to build the coloured rectangles.

Is there a way to do this in an automated way instead of manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a great use case for [run length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding).

Example as below:

```r
library(ggplot2)

# Data from question
positionx <- c(1:10)
pvalue <- c(0.1, 0.04, 0.03, 0.02, 0.001, 0.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.001, 0.002)
df <- data.frame(cbind(positionx, pvalue))

# Sort data (just to be sure)
df <- df[order(df$positionx),]

# Do run length encoding magic
threshold <- 0.05
rle <- rle(df$pvalue < threshold)
starts <- {ends <- cumsum(rle$lengths)} - rle$lengths + 1

df2 <- data.frame(
  xmin = df$positionx[starts],
  xmax = df$positionx[ends],
  type = rle$values
)

# Filter on type
df2 <- df2[df2$type == TRUE, ] # Satisfied threshold criterium

ggplot(df2, aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = 0, ymax = 1)) +
  geom_rect()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: The solution of teunbrand works perfectly, thank you very much!!